# Stripes encoding works weird

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, stripes

I am sending some variables from stripes:param to another actionbean in order to show them in another jsp file. 
The problem is that if a variable has non-english characters like (ä,ö,...) stripes:param encode them to some wired format. I used ecoding tags in my jsp but doesn't work. 
Since stripes:param is inside a stripes:link, could it be something with stripes:link? 
For example if 'fname' in first jsp has a character like 'ö' stripes converts it to some other characters when it shows it in second jsp!
Any idea what is happening here?

first jsp

```
<stripes:link beanclass="se.theducation.course.ui.action.student.StudentEditExcelAction" event="loadStudent" >
    <stripes:param name="fname" value="${array.getStudent().getFirstName() }" />
    <stripes:param name="lname" value="${array.getStudent().getLastName() }" />
    edit
</stripes:link>
```

StudentEditExcelAction.java

```
@UrlBinding("/Student/editExcel.action")
public class StudentEditExcelAction implements ActionBean {

private String fname;
private String lname;

@DefaultHandler
@DontValidate
public Resolution edit() {
    return forward("editExcel");
}

@DontValidate
public Resolution loadStudent() {
    System.out.println("utbildare: " + school); //TODO delete this later
    return forward("editExcel");
}
```

second jsp

```
<table class="solid" style="margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px; width:900px">
    <tr class="solid">
        <td class="solid">
            <tags:labeled label="Firstname:"><br />
            <stripes:text name="fname"/>
            </tags:labeled>
        </td>
        <td class="solid">
            <tags:labeled label="Lastname:"><br />
            <stripes:text name="lname"/>
            </tags:labeled>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the problem was about encoding so I added the following servlet filter to my web.xml and it works!

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to add

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>LocalePicker.Locales</param-name>
    <param-value>fr_FR:UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
```

in the configuration of filter `StripesFilter` in web.xml, as defined here: https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/STRIPES/pages/492001/Localization

Answer (score 0):

For me working example is this:

https://github.com/pojosontheweb/woko/blob/develop/core/src/main/java/woko/util/SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java

Copy that class into your project and then include it in web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>project.name.SiteFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>   
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```